# Pandas: Assigning multiple *new* columns simultaneously

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `df` with a column containing labels for each row (in addition to some relevant data for each row).  I have a dictionary `labeldict` with keys equal to the possible labels and values equal to 2-tuples of information related to that label.  I'd like to tack two new columns onto my frame, one for each part of the 2-tuple corresponding to the label for each row.

Here is the setup:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
n = 10

labels = list('abcdef')
colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue']
sizes = ['small', 'medium', 'large']

labeldict = {c: (np.random.choice(colors), np.random.choice(sizes)) for c in labels}

df = pd.DataFrame({'label': np.random.choice(labels, n), 
                   'somedata': np.random.randn(n)})
```

I can get what I want by running:

```
df['color'], df['size'] = zip(*df['label'].map(labeldict))
print df

  label  somedata  color    size
0     b  0.196643    red  medium
1     c -1.545214  green   small
2     a -0.088104  green   small
3     c  0.852239  green   small
4     b  0.677234    red  medium
5     c -0.106878  green   small
6     a  0.725274  green   small
7     d  0.934889    red  medium
8     a  1.118297  green   small
9     c  0.055613  green   small
```

But how can I do this if I don't want to manually type out the two columns on the left side of the assignment?  I.e. how can I create multiple new columns on the fly.  For example, if I had 10-tuples in `labeldict` instead of 2-tuples, this would be a real pain as currently written.  Here are a couple things that don't work:

```
# set up attrlist for later use
attrlist = ['color', 'size']

# non-working idea 1)
df[attrlist] = zip(*df['label'].map(labeldict))

# non-working idea 2)
df.loc[:, attrlist] = zip(*df['label'].map(labeldict))
```

This does work, but seems like a hack:

```
for a in attrlist:
    df[a] = 0
df[attrlist] = zip(*df['label'].map(labeldict))
```

Better solutions?

Comment: FYI your last method will work in 0.13 (without initially creating the column)

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I have a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25896241/creating-columns-and-assigning-a-constant-vector-to-every-row) inspired by your comment here. I am having a similar problem to the one stated here

Comment: Seems like the answer is pythonically simple: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34074894/3494126

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use merge instead:

```
>>> ld = pd.DataFrame(labeldict).T
>>> ld.columns = ['color', 'size']
>>> ld.index.name = 'label'
>>> df.merge(ld.reset_index(), on='label')
  label  somedata  color    size
0     b  1.462108    red  medium
1     c -2.060141  green   small
2     c  1.133769  green   small
3     c  0.042214  green   small
4     e -0.322417    red  medium
5     e -1.099891    red  medium
6     e -0.877858    red  medium
7     e  0.582815    red  medium
8     f -0.384054    red   large
9     d -0.172428    red  medium
```

Comment: you can get away without the reset_index using merge's left_index and right_on.

Comment: Note that `merge` generates a new dataframe instead of adding columns to an existing one. Also if there is no index column in the dataframe of your problem, you can't use merge.

Answer (score 33):

Just use `result_type='expand'` in [pandas apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
df
Out[78]: 
   a  b
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9

df[['mean', 'std', 'max']]=df[['a','b']].apply(mathOperationsTuple, axis=1, result_type='expand')

df
Out[80]: 
   a  b  mean  std  max
0  0  1   0.5  0.5  1.0
1  2  3   2.5  0.5  3.0
2  4  5   4.5  0.5  5.0
3  6  7   6.5  0.5  7.0
4  8  9   8.5  0.5  9.0
```

and here some copy paste code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(5,2), columns=['a','b'])
print('df',df, sep='\n')
print()
def mathOperationsTuple(arr):
    return np.mean(arr), np.std(arr), np.amax(arr)

df[['mean', 'std', 'max']]=df[['a','b']].apply(mathOperationsTuple, axis=1, result_type='expand')
print('df',df, sep='\n')
```

Comment: Use of `apply` was what I wanted but although this answer was helpful it made the assignment and function interdependent based on the order of the columns used as input and output. I ended up using the approach from @EricNess instead to capture this mapping entirely within the helper function.

Comment: Better use this anser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76098907/7128154

Answer (score 8):

Instead of doing what you're doing with labeldict, you could make that information into a DataFrame and then join it with your original one:

```
>>> labeldf = pandas.DataFrame([(np.random.choice(colors), np.random.choice(sizes)) for c in labels], columns=['color', 'size'], index=labels)
>>> df.join(labeldf, on='label')
  label  somedata  color    size
0     a -1.709973    red  medium
1     b  0.099109   blue  medium
2     a -0.427323    red  medium
3     b  0.474995   blue  medium
4     b -2.819208   blue  medium
5     d -0.998888    red   small
6     b  0.713357   blue  medium
7     d  0.331989    red   small
8     e -0.906240  green   large
9     c -0.501916   blue   large
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add multiple columns to a `DataFrame` as part of a method chain, you can use `apply`. The first step is to create a function that will transform a row represented as a `Series` into the form you want. Then you can call `apply` to use this function on each row.

```
def append_label_attributes(row: pd.Series, labelmap: dict) -> pd.Series:
    result = row.copy()
    result['color'] = labelmap[result['label']][0]
    result['size'] = labelmap[result['label']][1]
    return result

df = (
    pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'label': np.random.choice(labels, n),
        'somedata': np.random.randn(n)}
    )
    .apply(append_label_attributes, axis='columns', labelmap=labeldict)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
df[['color','size']] = list(df['label'].apply(labeldict))
```

Answer (score 0):

## `pandas` `apply` method support this out of the box

### code

`demo.py`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2), columns=['a', 'b'])
df2 = df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda ser: pd.Series({
    'mean': ser.mean(),
    'std': ser.std(ddof=0),
    'max': np.amax(ser.to_numpy())
}), axis=1)
df2 = pd.concat((df, df2), axis=1)
```

### output

```
>>> from demo import df, df2
>>> df
   a  b
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9
>>> df2
   a  b  mean  std  max
0  0  1   0.5  0.5  1.0
1  2  3   2.5  0.5  3.0
2  4  5   4.5  0.5  5.0
3  6  7   6.5  0.5  7.0
4  8  9   8.5  0.5  9.0
```

### background

A few years after writing my first answer to this question I got a bit better overview of the mechanics in pandas.

The `func` argument in [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) takes a function: `pd.Series -> Any` whereas from the type of `Any` the exact processing of the returned value into the `DataFrame` is deduced.

> Objects passed to the function are Series objects whose index is either the DataFrame’s index (axis=0) or the DataFrame’s columns (axis=1). By default (result_type=None), the final return type is inferred from the return type of the applied function.

If you pass a lambda function: `pd.Series` -> `pd.Series`, you get exactly the required behavior.

#### Note

`apply` can also be applied on `pd.groupby` outputs, achieving a more flexible alternative to `.aggregate`. You can find an example in the question: [Python pandas groupby aggregate on multiple columns, then pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76046539/7128154)