# How to assign a dataframe to the columns of another?

Tags: pandas

Let

1. `df` be some dataframe;
2. `X` be a tuple containing the numerical indices of some of `df`'s columns;
3. `df0` be the sub-dataframe of `df` given by `df.iloc[:, X]`; and
4. `df1` be some transform of `df0` such that `len(df1)` equals `len(df0)`, and `df1.columns` equals `df0.columns`;

Hence `df.iloc[:, X]` has the same shape as `df1`.

I want to *update* the contents of the `df.iloc[:, X]` sub-dataframe by assigning `df1` to it.

If I do the naive thing:

```
df.iloc[:, X] = df1
```

most of the updated columns (though not all, curiously enough) get filled with `NaN`s, even though there are no `NaN`s in `df1`.

I figure that this has to do with the indexing of `df1` with respect to `df`, but couldn't find a solution.  (One Hail-Mary-Pass thing I tried was setting `df1.index = df.index`, but it didn't work<sup>1</sup>.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Not surprising, since I don't know what I'm doing, though not for lack of trying.  I've read the Pandas book, as well as several tutorials, blogs, etc., and some of the source code too, but working with Pandas remains somewhat Russian-roulette-ish for me.</sup>

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829748/pandas-assigning-multiple-new-columns-simultaneously and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23307301/pandas-replacing-column-values-in-dataframe

Comment: `df.iloc[:, X] = df1` should work (unless, perhaps, you do something funny to the index of `df1`). Can you create a minimal example showing the unexpected behaviour and post it here?

Comment: `df.reset_index(False).iloc[:, X] = df1.reset_index(False)` might be worth a shot...