# How to set values of two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which returns a tuple with two elements in python. I'm going to use this function to create two new columns in my dataframe in pandas. This is the code I have now

```
df['A','B'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_fun (X['A'], x['B'], other_arguments)[0:2], axis=1)
```

`my_fun` returns tuples with 5 elements and I'm taking the first two elements to create the new columns.
However it creates only one column and set the value of that column to the tuple that `my_fun` returns. How can I create two columns instead of one?

Comment: this should help https://stackoverflow.com/q/34074663/9754169

Comment: It will obviously create one column with values of column A and B in tuple. What is your sample Dataframe and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[['A','B']] = df.apply(lambda x: my_fun (X['A'], x['B'], other_arguments)[0:2], axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df['A'], df['B'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_fun(x['A'], x['B'], other_arguments)[:2], axis=1)
```

if `my_fun` returns a tuple with 5 elements and you only want to keep the first 2, then use a slice with the function call `[:2]`