# Applying a function to two columns of pandas dataframe to get two new columns

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, apply

I have a pandas data frame with columns `Longitude` and `Latitude`. I'd like to get `X` and `Y` from them. There is a function in `utm` called `from_latlon` that does this. It receives `Latitude` and `Longitude` and gives `[X,Y]`. Here's what I do:

```py
    def get_X(row):
        return utm.from_latlon(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'])[0]

    def get_Y(row):
        return utm.from_latlon(row['Latitude'], row['Longitude'])[1] 

    df['X'] = df.apply(get_X, axis=1)
    df['Y'] = df.apply(get_Y, axis=1)
```

I'd like to define a function `get_XY` and apply `from_latlon` just one time to save time. I took a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353729/pandas-how-to-use-apply-function-to-multiple-columns) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914937/applying-function-with-multiple-arguments-to-create-a-new-pandas-column) but I could not find a way to make two columns with one `apply` function. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can return a list from your function:

```
d = pandas.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "B": [8, 88, 0, -8, -88]
})

def foo(row):
    return [row["A"]+row["B"], row["A"]-row["B"]]

>>> d.apply(foo, axis=1)
    A   B
0   9  -7
1  90 -86
2   3   3
3  -4  12
4 -83  93
```

You can also return a Series.  This lets you specify the column names of the return value:

```
def foo(row):
    return pandas.Series({"X": row["A"]+row["B"], "Y": row["A"]-row["B"]})

>>> d.apply(foo, axis=1)
    X   Y
0   9  -7
1  90 -86
2   3   3
3  -4  12
4 -83  93
```

Comment: Based on your first solution, I use `temp = d.apply(foo, axis=1)` and then do `d['sum'] = [item[0] for item in temp]` and `d['subtract'] = [item[1] for item in temp]`. Is there a better way to do it. If I do `d[['sum','subtract']] = d.apply(foo, axis=1)` I get an error. I guess at this point it's a matter of returning the result into the original data frame. Your second solution doesn't work for me unfortunately because of my specific function. Thanks.

Comment: @bikhaab: There's no simple way to assign multiple columns into a DataFrame at once, so that's kind of a separate issue.  You could use `concat` or `merge` to join the result DataFrame with your original one.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829748/pandas-assigning-multiple-new-columns-simultaneously) for some related ideas.

Answer (score 1):

I merged a couple of the answers from a similar thread and now have a generic multi-column in, multi-column out template I use in Jupyter/pandas:

```
# plain old function doesn't know about rows/columns, it just does its job.
def my_func(arg1,arg2):
    return arg1+arg2, arg1-arg2  # return multiple responses

df['sum'],df['difference'] = zip(*df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x['first'],x['second']),axis=1))
```