# Python pandas groupby aggregate on multiple columns, then pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot, data-cleaning

In Python, I have a pandas DataFrame similar to the following:

```
Item | shop1 | shop2 | shop3 | Category
------------------------------------
Shoes| 45    | 50    | 53    | Clothes
TV   | 200   | 300   | 250   | Technology
Book | 20    | 17    | 21    | Books
phone| 300   | 350   | 400   | Technology
```

Where shop1, shop2 and shop3 are the costs of every item in different shops.
Now, I need to  return a DataFrame, after some data cleaning, like this one:

```
Category (index)| size| sum| mean | std
----------------------------------------
```

where size is the number of items in each Category and sum, mean and std are related to the same functions applied to the 3 shops. How can I do these operations with the split-apply-combine pattern (groupby, aggregate, apply,...) ?

Can someone help me out? I'm going crazy with this one...thank you!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Edited for Pandas 0.22+ considering the deprecation of the use of dictionaries in a group by aggregation.

We set up a very similar dictionary where we use the keys of the dictionary to specify our functions and the dictionary itself to rename the columns.

```
rnm_cols = dict(size='Size', sum='Sum', mean='Mean', std='Std')
df.set_index(['Category', 'Item']).stack().groupby('Category') \
  .agg(rnm_cols.keys()).rename(columns=rnm_cols)

            Size   Sum        Mean        Std
Category                                     
Books          3    58   19.333333   2.081666
Clothes        3   148   49.333333   4.041452
Technology     6  1800  300.000000  70.710678
```

---

***option 1***
*use [`agg`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation) ← link to docs*

```
agg_funcs = dict(Size='size', Sum='sum', Mean='mean', Std='std')
df.set_index(['Category', 'Item']).stack().groupby(level=0).agg(agg_funcs)

                  Std   Sum        Mean  Size
Category                                     
Books        2.081666    58   19.333333     3
Clothes      4.041452   148   49.333333     3
Technology  70.710678  1800  300.000000     6
```

***option 2***
**more for less**
*use [`describe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.describe.html) ← link to docs*

```
df.set_index(['Category', 'Item']).stack().groupby(level=0).describe().unstack()

            count        mean        std    min    25%    50%    75%    max
Category                                                                   
Books         3.0   19.333333   2.081666   17.0   18.5   20.0   20.5   21.0
Clothes       3.0   49.333333   4.041452   45.0   47.5   50.0   51.5   53.0
Technology    6.0  300.000000  70.710678  200.0  262.5  300.0  337.5  400.0
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @piRSquared, if we want to apply multiple functions for the same column dictionary wouldn't work. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: @CanCeylan This uses groupby and aggregation on a Pandas Series.  It behaves differently for a DataFrame.

Answer (score 41):

```
df.groupby('Category').agg({'Item':'size','shop1':['sum','mean','std'],'shop2':['sum','mean','std'],'shop3':['sum','mean','std']})
```

Or if you want it across all shops then:

```
df1 = df.set_index(['Item','Category']).stack().reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2':'Shops',0:'costs'})
df1.groupby('Category').agg({'Item':'size','costs':['sum','mean','std']})
```

Answer (score 3):

## Aggregate rows with information from different columns

Here some example using multiindex (for simplicity). Of course you can shorten up the redundant outputs for `(shop1-3, mean/std)` by some dict comprehension, but for simplicity I skipped that.

The **special** thing about this answer, is that we use aggregations operating on different columns simultaneously, for instance `("all_shops", "mean")` takes the mean over all grouped rows of the columns `['shop1', 'shop2', 'shop3']`.

### input / output

```
df:
    Item  shop1  shop2  shop3    Category
0  Shoes     45     50     53     Clothes
1     TV    200    300    250  Technology
2   Book     20     17     21       Books
3  phone    300    350    400  Technology

df_agg:
           general   all_shops             shop1             shop2             shop3            
             count        mean        std   mean        std   mean        std   mean         std
Category                                                                                        
Books          1.0   19.333333   1.699673   20.0        NaN   17.0        NaN   21.0         NaN
Clothes        1.0   49.333333   3.299832   45.0        NaN   50.0        NaN   53.0         NaN
Technology     2.0  300.000000  64.549722  250.0  70.710678  325.0  35.355339  325.0  106.066017
```

### code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

    df = pd.DataFrame([
        ["Shoes", 45, 50, 53, "Clothes"],
        ["TV", 200, 300, 250, "Technology"],
        ["Book", 20, 17, 21, "Books"],
        ["phone", 300, 350, 400, "Technology"],
        ], columns=["Item", "shop1", "shop2", "shop3", "Category"]
    )
    print(f"df:\n{df}")

    df_agg = df.groupby("Category").apply(func=lambda df_gr: pd.Series({
        ("general", "count"): len(df_gr),
        ("all_shops", "mean"): df_gr[['shop1', 'shop2', 'shop3']].mean().mean(),
        ("all_shops", "std"): np.std(df_gr[['shop1', 'shop2', 'shop3']].to_numpy()),
        ("shop1", "mean"): df_gr['shop1'].mean(),
        ("shop1", "std"): df_gr['shop1'].std(),
        ("shop2", "mean"): df_gr['shop2'].mean(),
        ("shop2", "std"): df_gr['shop2'].std(),
        ("shop3", "mean"): df_gr['shop3'].mean(),
        ("shop3", "std"): df_gr['shop3'].std(),
    }))
    print(f"\ndf_agg:\n{df_agg}")
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to calculate aggregate metrics for all shops, not for each individually. To do that, you can first [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) your dataframe and then group by `Category`:

```
stacked = df.set_index(['Item', 'Category']).stack().reset_index()
stacked.columns = ['Item', 'Category', 'Shop', 'Price']
stacked.groupby('Category').agg({'Price':['count','sum','mean','std']})
```

Which results in

```
           Price                             
           count   sum        mean        std
Category                                     
Books          3    58   19.333333   2.081666
Clothes        3   148   49.333333   4.041452
Technology     6  1800  300.000000  70.710678
```