# Aggregating dictionary with Nested Structure in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, aggregate

I want to aggregate a Python Dictionary I have by date and by sales. For example, my dictionary looks like this:

```
{'Sales Data Year': 2022,
'rawData': [{
'id': 23490832405,
'sum': [100, 4324, 4564, 23, 77],
'startTime': '2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
'endTime': '2022-01-01T08:00:00.000Z',
'indicator': 8,
'clients': 324},
{'id': 4239084235,
'sum': [321, 456, 234, 7865, 233],
'startTime': '2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z',
'endTime': '2022-01-01T08:00:00.000Z',
'indicator': 8,
'clients': 543},
{'id': 235908221,
'sum': [100, 4324, 4564, 23, 77],
'startTime': '2022-01-01T08:00:00.000Z',
'endTime': '2022-01-01T16:00:00.000Z',
'indicator': 8,
'clients': 324},
{'id': 23534543663,
'sum': [654, 43, 564, 654, 823],
'startTime': '2022-01-01T16:00:00.000Z',
'endTime': '2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z',
'indicator': 8,
'clients': 6453},
{'id': 429234802452,
'sum': [423, 4324, 4431, 23, 765],
'startTime': '2022-01-02T00:00:00.000Z',
'endTime': '2022-01-02T08:00:00.000Z',
'indicator': 8,
'clients': 867}]}
```

How can I aggregate everything by date (e.g., 2022-01-01, 2022-01-02, ...), not by time? For example, I want to be able to sum all the values in the `sum` Array, sum the `clients` field, and average the `indicator` field.

I've tried looping through the dictionary, but I am having a hard time dealing with combining the dates since they have time stamps attached.

Comment: @esqew I've tried looping through the dictionary, but I am having a hard time dealing with combining the dates since they have time stamps attached.

Comment: Can you share the code of your attempt as a [mre] in the body of your question in accordance with [ask] to illustrate where *specifically* you're getting stuck?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a datetime to date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3743222/how-do-i-convert-a-datetime-to-date)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
#Assign your data to a dictionary
test = {'Sales Data Year': 2022, 'rawData': [{ ....... your full data }

#your useful data is in key rawData 
df = pd.DataFrame(test['rawData'])
df['sum'] = df['sum'].apply(lambda x: sum(x))
df['startTime'] = df['startTime'].apply(pd.to_datetime)

#Group by date and print the sum
print(df.groupby([df['startTime'].dt.date]).sum())
```

Check this question to get other values like mean, std etc.
[Python pandas groupby aggregate on multiple columns, then pivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172970/python-pandas-groupby-aggregate-on-multiple-columns-then-pivot)