# Match Substring in a column Based on Some Multiple Filter Values in Another column and Aggregate the Count Using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, substring

I am struggling to find the sum of count column based on subtring present in a column **Name**. The substring should co exist with the other multiple values present in another column that is **Error Name**. If substring (e.g. Ehsan) matches and another column i.e. **Error Name** has those multiple values (Device and Line Error) then i would some the count in **Count** Column. Remember I have to sum only those count which has substring Ehsan in **Name** and Device and Line Error in **Error Name**
Below is my Raw Data:

[image]

And my output should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After Editing The Question:**
You need to select rows that contain `Ehsan` and then use [`pandas.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the result `dataframe` like below:

```
mask_name = df['Name'].str.contains(r'.*(?:Ehsan).*')
mask_err = df['Error Name'].str.contains(r'(?:\bLine Error\b|\bDevice\b)')
df = df[mask_name & mask_err]
df.groupby(['Name', 'Error Name'])['Count'].sum().reset_index()
```

**Before Editing The  Question:**
You can write a mask for columns `Name` and `Error Name` with `regex` then select rows that have True in two masks and sum `Count` for those rows with [`pandas.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`pandas.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) like below:

```
mask_name = df['Name'].str.contains(r'.*(?:Ehsan).*')
mask_err = df['Error Name'].str.contains(r'(?:\bLine Error\b|\bDevice\b)')
df.loc[mask_name & mask_err, 'Count'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks it worked , what if i want to show each Different occurrence of Ehsan in resulted Dataframe along Device and Line Error and report the count separately in Dataframe? Can you please then modify your code?

Comment: @Ehsan125, welcome, Can you add desired output to your question?

Comment: i have edited the source data and output desired data, please remember now Name column has duplicate name and in final output it would be single occurrence based on Error Name Column. If Error Name would change then that may occur again.

Comment: Thanks it worked , but tell me what first is doing in agg function, what is its use? And one more thing in your first solution you have to keep the space of or condition like this Line Error|Device can you please incorporate this as well in the new solution that you provided please

Comment: In `agg` after groupby we can use a function on other columns like `sum`, `first`, `last`, ... but in your problem, I think you don't need `agg`. You need groupby on two columns the sum on `count`. read this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172970/python-pandas-groupby-aggregate-on-multiple-columns-then-pivot)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str.contains` and `sum` here:

```
total = df[df["Name"].str.contains(r'\bEhsan\b', flags=re.I, na=False, regex=True)]["Count"].sum()
```

Comment: I have some NA/NaN values as well in my actual data and giving this error when i applied your code. ValueError: Cannot mask with non-boolean array containing NA / NaN values

Comment: @Ehsan125 Try adding the `na=False` flag to the `str.contains` call.

Comment: Thanks it worked , what if i want to show each Different occurrence of Ehsan along Device and Line Error and report the count separately in Dataframe? Can you please then modify your code?