# Multiple aggregations on multiple columns in Python polars

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, aggregate, python-polars

Checking out how to implement binning with Python polars, I can easily calculate aggregates for individual columns:

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

t, v = np.arange(0, 100, 2), np.arange(0, 100, 2)
df = pl.DataFrame({"t": t, "v0": v, "v1": v})
df = df.with_column((pl.datetime(2022,10,30) + pl.duration(seconds=df["t"])).alias("datetime")).drop("t")

df.groupby_dynamic("datetime", every="10s").agg(pl.col("v0").mean())
┌─────────────────────┬──────┐
│ datetime            ┆ v0   │
│ ---                 ┆ ---  │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64  │
╞═════════════════════╪══════╡
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:00 ┆ 4.0  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:10 ┆ 14.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:20 ┆ 24.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:30 ┆ 34.0 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 ┆ ...  │
```

or calculate multiple aggregations like

```py
df.groupby_dynamic("datetime", every="10s").agg([
    pl.col("v0").mean().alias("v0_binmean"),
    pl.col("v0").count().alias("v0_bincount")
])
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┐
│ datetime            ┆ v0_binmean ┆ v0_bincount │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---         │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64        ┆ u32         │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:00 ┆ 4.0        ┆ 5           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:10 ┆ 14.0       ┆ 5           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:20 ┆ 24.0       ┆ 5           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:30 ┆ 34.0       ┆ 5           │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 ┆ ...        ┆ ...         │
```

or calculate one aggregation for multiple columns like

```py
cols = [c for c in df.columns if "datetime" not in c]
df.groupby_dynamic("datetime", every="10s").agg([
     pl.col(f"{c}").mean().alias(f"{c}_binmean")
     for c in cols
])
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬────────────┐
│ datetime            ┆ v0_binmean ┆ v1_binmean │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:00 ┆ 4.0        ┆ 4.0        │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:10 ┆ 14.0       ┆ 14.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:20 ┆ 24.0       ┆ 24.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:30 ┆ 34.0       ┆ 34.0       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 ┆ ...        ┆ ...        │
```

**However**, combining both approaches fails!

```py
df.groupby_dynamic("datetime", every="10s").agg([
    [
    pl.col(f"{c}").mean().alias(f"{c}_binmean"),
    pl.col(f"{c}").count().alias(f"{c}_bincount")
    ]
    for c in cols
])
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/tmp/ipykernel_2666/421808935.py", line 2, in <cell line: 2>
    df.groupby_dynamic("datetime", every="10s").agg([

  File ".../3.10.9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/groupby.py", line 924, in agg
    .agg(aggs)

  File ".../3.10.9/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/lazyframe/groupby.py", line 55, in agg
    raise TypeError(msg)

TypeError: expected 'Expr | Sequence[Expr]', got '<class 'list'>'
```

Is there a "polarustic" approach to calculate multiple statistical parameters for multiple (all) columns of the dataframe in one go?

related, pandas-specific: [Python pandas groupby aggregate on multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43172970/10197418)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various ways of selecting multiple columns "at once" in polars:

```py
df.select(pl.all()).columns
# ['v0', 'v1', 'datetime']

df.select(pl.col("v0", "v1")).columns       # by name(s)
# ['v0', 'v1']

df.select(pl.exclude("datetime")).columns   # by exclusion
# ['v0', 'v1']
```

The output column names can be controlled using the  [`.name.*`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/name.html) methods

e.g. [`name.suffix()`](https://docs.pola.rs/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.name.suffix.html#polars.Expr.name.suffix)

```py
df.select(pl.exclude("datetime").mean().name.suffix("_binmean"))
```

```py
shape: (1, 2)
┌────────────┬────────────┐
│ v0_binmean ┆ v1_binmean │
│ ---        ┆ ---        │
│ f64        ┆ f64        │
╞════════════╪════════════╡
│ 49.0       ┆ 49.0       │
└────────────┴────────────┘
```

As such, we can rewrite your example using:

```py
df.group_by_dynamic("datetime", every="10s").agg(
   pl.exclude("datetime").mean().name.suffix("_binmean"),
   pl.exclude("datetime").count().name.suffix("_bincount")
)
```

```py
shape: (10, 5)
┌─────────────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ datetime            ┆ v0_binmean ┆ v1_binmean ┆ v0_bincount ┆ v1_bincount │
│ ---                 ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ u32         ┆ u32         │
╞═════════════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:00 ┆ 4.0        ┆ 4.0        ┆ 5           ┆ 5           │
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:10 ┆ 14.0       ┆ 14.0       ┆ 5           ┆ 5           │
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:20 ┆ 24.0       ┆ 24.0       ┆ 5           ┆ 5           │
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:30 ┆ 34.0       ┆ 34.0       ┆ 5           ┆ 5           │
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:40 ┆ 44.0       ┆ 44.0       ┆ 5           ┆ 5           │
│ 2022-10-30 00:00:50 ┆ 54.0       ┆ 54.0       ┆ 5           ┆ 5           │
│ 2022-10-30 00:01:00 ┆ 64.0       ┆ 64.0       ┆ 5           ┆ 5           │
│ 2022-10-30 00:01:10 ┆ 74.0       ┆ 74.0       ┆ 5           ┆ 5           │
│ 2022-10-30 00:01:20 ┆ 84.0       ┆ 84.0       ┆ 5           ┆ 5           │
│ 2022-10-30 00:01:30 ┆ 94.0       ┆ 94.0       ┆ 5           ┆ 5           │
└─────────────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
```