# Merge predicted results into dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

In my predicted dataframe I have three columns, I want to merge all those three columns with the original dataset. How can I achieve this?

```
ds = pd.read_csv("final10.csv")
X = ds.iloc[:, 3:-4].values
y = ds.iloc[:,-1].values
testcase = pd.read_csv("testcase.csv")
testcase=testcase.iloc[:,3:-1].values

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
clf = LogisticRegression(solver="newton-cg", multi_class='multinomial')
clf.fit(X, y)
y_pred1 = clf.predict_proba(testcase)
testcase['procurement']=pd.Series(y_pred1)
```

The error I'm getting is "Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [adding multiple columns to pandas simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050539/adding-multiple-columns-to-pandas-simultaneously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign 3 columns in `y_pred1` to a single column in dataframe `testcase`. Thats the source of error. You will have to use three different target columns in the dataframe to assign the three prediction columns.

So for example, if your `y` has three unique classes (labels) in the data, the `predict_proba()` output (`y_pred1` in this case) will be of shape `[n, 3]`.

You can combine this 2-d array to the existing dataframe in multiple ways:

**Simple way**: Assign each column separately

```
testcase['procurement_class0'] = y_pred1[:,0]
testcase['procurement_class1'] = y_pred1[:,1]
testcase['procurement_class2'] = y_pred1[:,2]
```

Other ways: Look into these questions here:

- [adding multiple columns to pandas simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050539/adding-multiple-columns-to-pandas-simultaneously)
- [Pandas: Assigning multiple *new* columns simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829748/pandas-assigning-multiple-new-columns-simultaneously)